# Update Java alternatives

Tags: jdk

I've spent two days trying to switch over to Oracle Java because Android Studio doesn't like OpenJava.

I'm on the final (third) stage of setting the alternatives and have picked up the latest(?) suggestion from AskUbuntu, namely:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk/bin/java 1
```

All I get from the terminal is that the folder doesn't exist - in fact, it does.
Can any one help me here?

Comment: Can you please paste the error?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to install Java manually and spend two days on it.
Run in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

and everything will be installed for you.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thanks very much.